# Editing Datable before binding to listview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, datatable

hi this is my code to get datable from query but i need to check for some values like if there is 0 in any column then replace it with N.A.

```
Dim op As New cad
Dim dt As DataTable = op.Fetchbooks().Tables(0)
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
Dim rp As System.Data.DataRow
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
   ListView1.DataSource = dt
   ListView1.DataBind()
   DropDownList1.DataSource = dt
   DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Description"
   DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Description"
   DropDownList1.DataBind()
End if
```

so is there any way to check some values and edit in datable before binding ???

Comment: Couldn't you modify your query in `Fetchbooks` (i assume you are querying the database) to replace `0` with `N.A.`?

Comment: i am using mysql and dont know how can i edit this query SELECT `description`,MAX(CASE WHEN id_tariff = '38' THEN TRUNCATE(voice_rate,2) ELSE NULL END) AS `USD`,MAX(CASE WHEN id_tariff = '38' THEN TRUNCATE(voice_rate * 3.67,2) ELSE NULL END) AS `AED`,    MAX(CASE WHEN (id_tariff = '67') THEN TRUNCATE(voice_rate,2) ELSE NULL END) AS `Promo_rate`FROM voipswitch.tariffs WHERE id_tariff IN ('38', '67')GROUP BY `description`; i need to check whether promo rate and usd are same then show N.A. insted promo rate, can u help with it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if possible i would modify your sql-query in `Fetchbooks` instead  to replace `0` with `N.A.`. I assume you are querying the database.

However, if you want to do it in memory:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        If row.IsNull(col) OrElse row(col).ToString = "0" Then
            row(col) = "N.A."
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. i am getting this error for "N.A." but when i replace it with any number it works .  row(col) = "N.A." doesnt work but  row(col) = 0 works ..

Comment: @user1820110: Then it's an `Integer` column. You either have to select a varchar from your table (e.g. `SELECT CASE voice_rate
           WHEN 0 THEN 'N.A.'
           ELSE CAST(voice_rate as CHAR(50))
        END AS voice_rate_text`) or you have to add another column with type `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:  you can iterate through the table, making whatever value replacements are appropriate (assuming that your replacement values are type-compatible with what came from the query).

Something like:

```
 For Each row as DataRow in dt.Rows
    if row("columnname") = "left" then 
       row("columnname") = "right" 
 Next
```

Then bind it to the grid, and you should see your updated values.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the `DataTable` object you can manipulate it as you need:

```
For Each rp In dt.Select("COLUMN_A = '0'")
   rp("COLUMN_A") = "N.A."
Next
```

Note that this assumes that `COLUMN_A` is defined as a string type, not a numeric.

The challenge will be if you intend on saving this data back to it's source *and* you don't want the original `0` value to be saved instead of `N.A.`.  You could add `dt.AcceptChanges` immediately after the above loop so that it will appear as the `Fetchbooks` query had these values all along.

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. i am getting this error for "N.A." but when i replace it with any number it works ....

Comment: What is the `DataType` for this column?  That error makes me think that this column only allows number values, not string values.  Assigning `N.A.` will cause this type of error.